# Update datasouce in RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc

I am using SQL views to pass data to RDLC report. Now If I add a column to SQL view, How can I get this newly added column in RDLC report.

For now, I have to delete RDLC dataset and create new one every time which is not feasible at all. Hope someone have better way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open your report in any XML editor, locate your dataset and add more columns (of desired type) in Fields section. For example:

```
    <Field Name="NewColumnName">
      <DataField>NewColumnName</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
```