# How to redesign the Table in Report wizard in C#

Tags: rdlc

I created one rdlc file using report wizard in C#. Initially i chose some columns to display in the report.Later i want to include extra columns in the report which is already available in Table. Just i need to reopen the rdlc in report wizard and i want to change the table as Matrix instead of Stepped and add more columns,need to change group item.
Im using visual studio 2008, in that i cannot see some fields in that.Tool controls are get overlapping

How can i change some properties here or otherwise i have to delete the present rdlc file and start to Design the new report?
[image: ReportWizard]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it.

1. if you created DataSet in the same project and used it as a base for your wizard, then you can make changes in that DataSet, open your report, open ReportData (under View, if you are using VS2013), open DataSets, right-click on DataSet in question and select Refresh option. This should bring  new fields in DataSet definition of the report.
2. You can add new fields directly in XML definition of the report. To do it, right click on your report in Solution Explore and open it with XML editor. Here is the same question answered: [Update datasouce in RDLC report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919609/update-datasouce-in-rdlc-report/22921065#22921065)