# How to refresh RDLC dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc

In RDLC report, I have modified stored procedure to output additional two columns.

Now, when i open RDLC report and refresh the dataset (under report data) then, fields are just disappearing from report data view and dataset is not refreshed.

Can any one provide solution to refresh the dataaset so, additional two fields also appears.

I checked other post but, its all saying to `refresh` dataset or `edit` but, in that case, no fields appear how i shared above.

Comment: Are you using XSD datasets?

Comment: You can do it manually by changing dataset in report's xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919609/update-datasouce-in-rdlc-report/22921065#22921065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated data source with stored procedure and new field is appear.

It works by this way.

Thanks